# How to use the require function and TypeScript modules with tsify and watchify?

Tags: typescript, module, require, watchify, tsify

I am using tsify with watchify and VS Code. The compilation is successful without any warning or error.

I use this command:

```sh
cd html/wp-content/themes; watchify custom-theme/assets/ts/main.ts -p [ tsify ] -o custom-theme/assets/js/bundle.js -v
```

The `utils.ts` contents:

```
export module Utils {
    function getBrowserLanguage() : string {
        ...
    }

    function formatTime(secs: number): string {
        ...
    }
}
```

In each file where I use Utils, I put this:

```
const Utils = require("./utils");
```

at the top of the file.

The problem is that in the browser I get this console error:

```
ReferenceError: Utils is not defined (bundle.js)
```

All the TypeScript files are in the same folder.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "wp-content/themes/custom-theme/assets/js",
        "watch": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM"]
    },
    "include": [
        "wp-content/themes/custom-theme/assets/ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

What can I do to make the code work in the browser without that error?

Thank you.

## Update 1

This is [the repo](https://github.com/silviubogan/testing-modules-with-tsify) with a simplified example.